# unable to fetch all Keys and Values in map?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, unit-test

i am unable to fetch all Keys and Value simultaneously using forEach loop..

```
 for (Map<String,String> key : parameters) {

        queryParameters = key.values();//?
    }
```

Comment: Naman is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch them all simultaneously, you have to do it outside the loop:

```
Map<String,String> aMap = new Map<String,String>();
Set<String> mapKeys = aMap.keySet();
List<String> mapValues = aMap.values();
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm

If you absolutely need to all the keys inside a `for` loop (I don't know why... it sounds like bad practice to reference keys other than the one you're currently iterating), you can reference the `mapKeys` variable inside the for loop.

Or, just iterate and reference them one at a time as @MSCB described above

Comment: Yes. The map key values are a collection of set

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new Map<String,String>();

//iterate over the map key 
for (String key : myMap.keySet()) {

    system.debug('=======map key====='+key);
    //get the value based on key 
    system.debug('=======map value====='+myMap.get(key));
}
```